# "Personalized" escaped characters for different SE sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0

On math.SE, for instance, suppose one wants to TeX {1,2,3,...,n}.  Then to do this in LaTeX, one only needs to type `$\{1,2,3,...,n\}$`, but because SE markdown does not escape text inside of the $ delimiters, one is forced to type `$\\{1,2,3,...,n\\}$` to escape the backslash.  Similar problems exist with asterisks and underscores, which many times need to be escaped in order to avoid strange italicized text and missing subscripts.  I realize that not all websites would want text in between dollar delimiters escaped, so is it possible to have it enabled or disabled on certain sites?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that this should be implemented, but +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: I do fully agree. The only problem may be that TeX typed before the implementation may suddenly look weird...